# Tkinter layout doesn’t place buttons in the right place

Tags: python, tkinter, desktop-application, positioning, tkinter-button

I am trying to make an image viewer using Python Tkinter as a part of the course I am participating in and I am having some trouble with my code.

My problem is in the positioning of the forward and the exit button in the first image, The picture explains this [Look at the exit and forward(>>) button under the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suCul.jpg)
By the way, this problem is **only** appears in the first image but in the others, the positioning is perfect as shown in the picture [the back(<<) and the forward and the exit buttons are in the correct position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1MtC.jpg)

I have tried to read and debug the code multiple times, and I have even looked at the source code from the course, but I still can't seem to find the issue. Do you have any suggestions or recognize any bugs that I may have missed? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Here is all code:

```
#importing files
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk,Image

#the start of the program

root = Tk()

root.title("Image Viewer")

root.iconbitmap("E:\Marwan\PROGRAMMING\learning 
py\Tkinter\Projects\#2 Image Viewer\image viewer.ico")

#Image used
my_img1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("E:/Marwan\IMAGES/ai 
images/3.png"))

my_img2 = 
ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("E:\Marwan\IMAGES\megory2.PNG"))

my_img3 = 
ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("E:\Marwan\IMAGES\marwan.JPG"))

my_img4 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("E:/Marwan\IMAGES/ai 
images/ff.png"))

my_img5 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("E:/Marwan/IMAGES/ai 
images/55.png"))

my_img6 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("E:/Marwan/IMAGES/ai 
images/77.png"))

#list of the images
image_list = [my_img1,my_img2,my_img3,my_img4, my_img5,my_img6]

#previwing the images for the first time
my_label = Label(image=my_img1)
my_label.grid(row=0, column=0)

#function of the forward button
def forward(img_num):
    #globaling the vars
    global my_label

    global button_forward
   
    global button_back

    #forgetting the last img
    my_label.grid_forget()

    #previewing the current img
    my_label = Label(image=image_list[img_num-1])

    #commanding the buttons
    button_forward = Button(root, text='>>', command= lambda: 
    forward(img_num+1))

    button_back = Button(root, text='<<', command= lambda: 
    back(img_num-1))

    #disabling the forward button at the last img
    if img_num == 5:
       button_forward = Button(root, text='>>', state=DISABLED) 

    #gridding the widgets and appears it   
    my_label.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=3)

    button_forward.grid(row=1, column=2)

    button_back.grid(row=1, column=0)


#function of the forward button
def back(img_num):

    global my_label

    global button_forward

    global button_back
    
    my_label.grid_forget()

    my_label = Label(image=image_list[img_num-1])

    button_forward = Button(root, text='>>', command= lambda: 
    forward(img_num+1))

    button_back = Button(root, text='<<', command= lambda: 
    back(img_num-1))

    if img_num == 5:
        button_forward = Button(root, text='>>', state=DISABLED) 
    
    my_label.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=3)

    button_forward.grid(row=1, column=2)

    button_back.grid(row=1, column=0)




#Buttons of the first img
button_back = Button(root, text='<<',command= back, 
state=DISABLED)

button_exit = Button(root, text='Exit Program', 
command=root.quit)

button_forward = Button(root, text='>>', command= lambda: 
forward(2))

#gridding the widgets and appears it
button_back.grid(row=1, column=0)

button_exit.grid(row=1, column=1)

button_forward.grid(row=1, column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Pls post your code and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: sorry, I forgot that ,forgive it, I posted it now

Comment: Please format the code. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your forward() and back() and functions, you have set the columnspan to 3 using the following:

```
my_label.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=3)
```

However, when you load the image for the first time, you don’t set the columnspan value. Your code looks like this:

```
my_label = Label(image=my_img1)
my_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
```

That’s why the layout doesn’t work only for the first image. To fix it, just set the columnspan value:

```
my_label = Label(image=my_img1)
my_label.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=3)
```

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that in your forward and back function you have this. So it works as you expected when pressing back/forward.
`my_label.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=3)`

But when loading the image the first time you have this:

```
#previwing the images at the first time
my_label = Label(image=my_img1)
my_label.grid(row=0, column=0) <---
```

Change it to:
`my_label.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=3)`